# reinstall windows 7 (with ubuntu and windows7)

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I have windows 7 already installed on my computer but I need to reinstall it. I have no data on my windows and I do not care if anything happens to the old windows, but I need to keep my ubuntu safe! I will appreciate if you help me.

Comment: When installing Windows, just select the drive that already has Windows on it.

Comment: Step0: Backup data on Ubuntu partition.

Comment: If your Ubuntu install is in a logical partition backup partition table before reinstalling Windows. Sometimes Windows rewrites partition table and because it does not see Linux partitions does not rewrite it. It usually can be recovered with testdisk, but easier to have partition table and just restore that. Be sure you do not change partition table if restoring.  For MBR(msdos) not gpt: sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > parts.txt Then save parts.txt in case you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll BORK your bootloader when you do this.  Windows will install its' own MBR.

You'll be fine to re-install so long as you install to the correct partition, however you'll need to look at fixing GRUB once you've re-installed.